# Send non-native tokens using Wagmi and TrustWallet

Tags: reactjs, ethereum, erc20, wallet-connect, wagmi

I'm using wagmi and viem to transfer USDT in AVAX network from one address to another. But using **usePrepareContractWrite** hook I'm unable to figure out what is going wrong.

Using the below code, it initiates a smart contract call but it's displaying to transfer 0 AVAX instead of 5 USDT which I inputted. After successful confirmation, there's no USDT deducted from my wallet and SnowTrace shows "To" address as USDT contract address which is filled in the *address* field.

```
const { chain: activeChain } = useNetwork();

const { config: writeConfig } = usePrepareContractWrite({
    address: '0xdac17f958d2ee523a2206206994597c13d831ec7' // USDT contract address,
    chainId: activeChain?.id // 43114,
    abi: token === 'USDT' ? usdtAbi : erc20ABI,
    functionName: 'transfer',
    args: [
      receivingAddress,
      parseEther(usdcValue),
    ],
  });
```

[image]

Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.